# rsync implications of ACL backups between different source & dest file systems

Tags: rsync, btrfs, acl, nas, apfs

I'm having an issue using `rsyncd` (the daemon-ized version of rsync) to back up files from my macOS to my Synology server. Here's the command that fails:

```
% rsync -rlcAXtgoDiv --fake-super ~/scripts rsync://seamus@SynologyNAS-1/backups/scripts-backup/ > ~/scripts/log.txt 2>&1
```

This is the error: (in the logfile that I write and from command line):

```
rsync: [sender] write error: Broken pipe (32)
rsync error: error in socket IO (code 10) at io.c(848) [sender=3.2.7]
```

After some experimentation, I think I've narrowed the source of the problem to the use of the `-A` option:

```
--acls, -A               preserve ACLs (implies --perms)
--xattrs, -X             preserve extended attributes
--fake-super             store/recover privileged attrs using xattrs
```

As I understand it, the `--fake-super` option allows `rsync` to store ACLs as extended attributes without requiring `sudo`... but I'm weak on the implications of all of the namespace business in `man rsync`.

Further investigation led to the discovery that on the Synology server, this line was included in `/etc/rsyncd.conf`:

```
refuse options = acls
```

And so I edited `/etc/rsyncd.conf`, and commented the `refuse options = acls` line. When I re-ran the `rsync` command from earlier, it ran successfully :)

But hang on - I do have a question:

- The reported version of `rsync` on SynologyNAS-1 is:

```
rsync  version 3.1.2  protocol version 31
```

- In addition to the version difference (3.1.2 for Synology; 3.2.7 for macOS), the file system on Synology is `btrfs` - which is as opaque to me as APFS!

My question is this: Am I actually backing up the correct (macos-compatible) ACLs that I hope - or have I simply silenced the guards? Any thoughts on this would be welcome.

FWIW:
I'd like to think I'm actually doing a correct backup ***because*** when I do the backup without `rsyncd` I don't see these errors. I wanted to switch to `rsyncd` to avoid the needless encryption step (this is all on my LAN) & hopefully streamline the backups.

Comment: Do you need a backup of the acls?  How might you use the backup in the future?  If you want to know if it's sufficient, you should test restoring from it.

Comment: @BowlOfRed: I believe I do need accurate ACLs; the restoration would be going to my macOS. Testing could be problematic because I don't know which files have "special, macOS-unique" ACLs.